# Javascript Injected in browser

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I am using 4g wifi internet whenever I visit any page it keeps loading and when I look at a source code of the page there is a script injected into code

`<script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.80.196.101:8080/www/default/base.js'></script>`

Please help its really annoying.

Comment: Sounds like a virus on your machine or router.

Comment: Can you maybe post the content of that script to a text host site (pastebucket or whatever else) and link it in the question? There MIGHT be a valid reason for your dongle, browser or something else in the chain to be injecting that script (although I can't think of one). Maybe you should chat to this guy too -> http://superuser.com/questions/1050029/forward-http-access-to-another-ip-address-in-iptables and see if you have the same router?

Comment: Or it might be your ISP that does that.

Comment: Only visit HTTPS pages.

Comment: cross-site-dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/1050029/forward-http-access-to-another-ip-address-in-iptables

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I am getting the same code in my cellphone as well.

Comment: @Bergi thats right https pages opening without that code, also yes I've seen that post at superuser but didn't find the answer.

Comment: I am also victim of this virus :(

Comment: Are you using Zong 4G? I am facing same problem but just on Zong 4G not other ISPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out its my ISP injecting javascript in browsers. So I resolved it by using **No Javascript** addon in **Firefox** as well as in **Chrome**.

This would help for those who are facing the same issue.

Comment: But almost all of the sites depends on JS to run properly... !!

Comment: you can mark safe for any site using the same plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.

### Solved

This is the problem with `ZONG4G` Use the other ISP and you will be good.

Comment: I just experienced the issue yesterday, so i assume its still an issue?