# Embedded javascript source on my header possible malware?

Tags: javascript, malware, virus

I have a problem on my code. I don't know if it is a malware because I double check my codes and the embedded javascript is not there. The malicious javascript embedded only on the live site but on my local is not.

Here's the sample embedded script on my header.

[image]

I don't know how can I removed that piece of embedded script. I also scan it on an online malware checker website and it doesn't detect the script.

Can you help me about this?

Comment: Can you fetch the contents of that URL? What sites does this impact? All or just a handful? What about a minimal test page with just a `<title>`?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684272/js-injection-disturbed-all-my-code) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880351/javascript-injected-in-browser) and lots more by searching for `1qa2ws`.

Comment: If this is a provider level injection then there's things to test. Does this happen on local sites? Does this happen over `https`? Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: @tadman it only happens on live sites but for local it is not.

Comment: This could be your ISP based on other similar questions. They're sneaking stuff into your pages which, honestly, should be flat-out illegal.

Comment: Funny thing, he could have lead with sharing the *base.js* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of the script, 10.165.197.14 (or any in the 10.x.x.x range) are private and not accessible on the internet, so it's not likely that someone has injected a malicious script into your site.

It's very likely one of the following:

1. You have malware on your local PC, and the malware is injecting the
   script into your browser
2. Your ISP is injecting it.
3. Some development tool/framework you are using to host the site is
   injecting it.

Try:

1. Check and see if it is injected into all sites or just yours.
2. Run a malware/adware scan, and possibly install ad-blocking software
3. Paste the URL (http://10.165.197.14:8080/www/default/base.js) and
   see what comes up. It may give you some insight into the intentions
   of whatever software is injecting the script.